# ZPL code printing differently in 2 printers

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I have the following ZPL code:

```
^XA^LH30,20^MD15^PW609
^FO0,20^AD^FD            Pull Sample Post-Login^FS
^FO0,45^AD^FDStudy ID :      ^FS
^FO0,70^AD^FDLIMS No :       3216665-TIME_FACT-STOR_COND^FS
^FO0,95^AD^FB590,2,,^FDMaterial Name : 2187- Abatacept (CTLA4g) for Injection 250mg/Vial^FS
^FO0,140^AD^FDBatch No :      ^FS
^FO0,165^AD^FDTime Point :    ^FS
^FO0,190^AD^FDStorage Conditions :^FS
^FO0,215^AD^FDRemoved By :    ^FS
^FO0,240^AD^FDRemoval Date :  
^FS^XZ
```

On a GX430T, the label width is 2x3 inch. It prints out field "Material Name:" fine by wrapping it to the 2nd line.

When try the same code in production, using ZM400 printer with a label width of (1x3 inch). It prints all the fields, except the Material Name field, you just see a blank line where the Material Name field should be.

I suspect that it's a issue with label width. How do I change the ZPL code that it takes into account the label width of the production ZM400 printer?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of these three commands might mess things up.

```
^LH30,20
^PW609
^FB590,2,,
```

^PW609 is print width of the label.

^LH30,20 sets home position at 30

^FB590 would create a field block that exceeds the print width of the label (30+590=620, which is > 609)

So maybe when you tweak these a bit, it might print it correctly?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.